# How to send control(key down) to ncurses application via pexpect

Tags: automation, command-line-interface, ncurses, pexpect

I have Linux application written with ncurses. I'm trying to automate it using pexpect but without success.

I can spawn an application and can work with output but I can't send arrow down key:

```
import pexpect
import time 
import sys, os

os.environ['LINES'] = "25"
os.environ['COLUMNS'] = "80"

child=pexpect.spawn("my_ncurses_app", maxread=4000, encoding="utf-8")
child.logfile=sys.stdout
child.setwinsize(25,80)

KEY_DOWN = '\033[B'

#close button appears on screen, After that I want to press down key twice and enter
child.expect("Close")

#ncurses_app sees KEY_DOWN as 3 different keys \033, [, B
child.send(KEY_DOWN)
child.send(KEY_DOWN)

child.sendline()
#ncurses_app sees enter as Int(10)
```

It works perfect for other CLI applications, but not for my.

Debugging shows what instead of 1 arrow down symbol application sees 3 different keys.

How I can send KEY_DOWN as one symbol? Possibly I should use smth other instead of pexpect, smth with low-level interaction with processes?

Comment: You need a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to get useful responses.